# Arraylist removing objects

Tags: java

I'm not sure why this code isn't working:

so we have a Card array :

```
Card[] hand = new Card[2];
```

Which contains two cards like:

```
 hand[0]=new Card("King","Hearts");
 hand[1]=new Card("Ace","Hearts");
```

however, when I try :

```
ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

// other method here that fills the deck with 52 cards

then:

```
deck.remove(hand[0]);
deck.remove(hand[1]);
```

then the hand is not removed

Comment: You have two different `ArrayList`s. You remove from the first, but expecting it to be removed from the second?

Comment: What do you mean by "the hand is not removed"? Your code only removes **one** Card from the deck ArrayList. You also should consider providing a little more meat to your question's bones so that we can answer it.

Comment: Did you override `equals` method in `Card` class? Post short example which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your code removes the card from the array list (deck) and not from the "hand"

Comment: sorry guys I added the second remove statement but it is not really relevant. When I check the size of deck after the remove it is still equal to 52 as it was before the remove

Comment: Please use enums for building a deck. This will make your life easier.

Comment: For better answers post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we could reproduce your problem. Without it we can only give you some general advices which may or may not help you. Especially important is code of `// other method here that fills the deck with 52 cards`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are not overriding the `Object.equals` method in your `Card` class by specifying the two desired `String`s (rank and suit) as equality criteria, which in turn means the `remove` method will return `false` and won't remove the `Card`.

I would also recommend overriding `hashCode`, although it isn't necessary in this context.

Most IDEs (such as Eclipse) have functionalities to generate those methods based on your desired equality criteria.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)'s a famous (yet debatable) SO question on the equals / hashCode contract in Java.

Comment: I just ran a simple test by creating two cards and checking if they were equal using .equals and it worked fine. Is there anything else that could be wrong?

Comment: @John that's a short test :D

Comment: Thanks, my .equals class in Card was comparing it to a Card instead of an object so it wasn't overriding.

Comment: @John That is canonical example of why we should add `@override` before each method we mean to override. If you would add this annotation before `equals(Card c)` compiler would inform you that you ware not actually overriding any methods.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to override `Object.equals` method, that determine whether two cards are same or not. If you are using `HashSet` or `HashMap` classes then you also need to override `hashCode()` method.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList.remove internally is using equals to determine which object to remove, so you need to implement equals.